# Unable to upload code to a NodeMCU Board

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I have 4 NodeMCU boards, 3 of them I can use and 1 I can't seem to upload any of my code to.  It does boot, and I can get a readout of it on the serial port.

On boot:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x40100000, len 1856, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0x63
load 0x3ffe8000, len 776, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x02
load 0x3ffe8310, len 552, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x79
csum 0x79

2nd boot version : 1.5
  SPI Speed      : 40MHz
  SPI Mode       : DIO
  SPI Flash Size & Map: 8Mbit(512KB+512KB)
jump to run user1 @ 1000

rf[112] : 03
rf[113] : 00
rf[114] : 01

SDK ver: 1.5.4(baaeaebb) compiled @ May 17 2016 19:23:54
phy ver: 972, pp ver: 10.1
```

I also tried doing a reset with the flash button held down:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,6)
```

I don't get any compile errors with my code, and the code works perfectly fine on the other 3 NodeMCU boards.  When I try to upload (regardless of boot mode) I see the blue light near the ESP8266 chip blink a couple of times, and then I get the following errors output:

```
Sketch uses 230061 bytes (22%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 34612 bytes (42%) of dynamic memory, leaving 47308 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

I've also tried grounding D0 and connecting the EN pin to 3.3v, which changes the boot mode to `ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,7)` and the red onboard LED turns on, but still doesn't allow me to upload code.

**ENVIRONMENT** (these settings work on all my other NodeMCU Boards and I did confirm this is a 1.0 board)
IDE: Arduino 1.8.0
Board: NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E)
CPU: 80 MHz
Flash Size: 4M (3M SPIFFS)
Upload Speed: 115200

Comment: c\heck the RST pin: http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=2096#p2112

Comment: @dandavis RST pin is not connected and works fine once activated.  You're seeing that boot mode come up because I was using the reset button to get the full output on the serial console.